# IS_BIG_ENDIAN macro works but not in #if

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

This is puzzling me:
If I comment out everything from the #if to the #endif the program compiles in C99 (TinyCC). With the conditional in it gives the error  *')' expected (got "0")* at the line before the #if clause

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define IS_BIG_ENDIAN (!*(unsigned char *)&(uint16_t){1})

#if IS_BIG_ENDIAN 
   struct ieee {     
     unsigned long sign:1;
     unsigned long expo:8;
     unsigned long mantissa:23;
    };   
   
#else
 
  struct ieee {   
    unsigned long mantissa:23;  
    unsigned long expo:8;
    unsigned long sign:1;
  };    

#endif


int main()
{  
 printf ("%d\n",IS_BIG_ENDIAN); 
}
```

Comment: `This is puzzling me:` This is expected behavior and all is fine and correct. Why is it puzzling?

Comment: I did'nt expect it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preprocessor commonly does not know how to evaluate all C expressions. Its capabilities are quite limited.

If you comment out if line with `#if`, the macro will not be evaluated. That's why you don't get an error.

But if the macro is evaluated you make the preprocessor parse the expression. Apparently it cannot do this.

Comment: But if I coment out the #if...#endif the macro is evaluated correctly in the main function...

Comment: Sure, because the compiler **can** evaluate it. Please note that the preprocessor and the compiler are two different beasts and use different languages.

Comment: “The preprocessor commonly does not know how to evaluate C expressions”→“The preprocessor commonly does not know how to evaluate all C expressions.” Certainly the preprocessor can evaluate the *constant-expression* in an `#if` directive per the rules in C 2018 6.10.1 4.

Answer (score 0):

The `#if` and `#elif` directives operate on a constant expression. In particular, the constant expression cannot use the value or address of any object (*lvalue*).

Notionally, the C program is translated in a sequence of translation phases 1 to 8. Preprocessing directives are executed at translation phase 4, but no objects are formed until translation phase 7. See "[Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases)" for more information about translation phases.

There is no standard way to supply the endianness as a constant expression for the preprocessor, but some implementations supply this information via predefined macros or via macros defined in a system header.

---

It should also be noted that the endianness of fundamental objects and the packing direction of successive bitfield members (i.e. whether packing starts at the most significant end or least significant end of a storage unit) are not related to each other, i.e. big-endianness does not imply that bitfield member packing starts at the most significant end or vice versa. As for endianness, the implementation may provide information about the packing order of bitfield members via predefined macros or via macros defined in a system header.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, I've corrected it. I was thinking there must be some internal representation of "concatenated string literal" after phase 6, but I guess it can be done by replacing a sequence of string literal tokens with a single, concatenated string literal token.

Answer (score -1):

For completeness I have found a test the preprocessor can manage:

```
      #define LITTLE_ENDIAN 0x41424344UL 
      #define BIG_ENDIAN    0x44434241UL
      #define PDP_ENDIAN    0x42414443UL
      #define ENDIAN_ORDER  ('ABCD') 
    
   #if ENDIAN_ORDER==BIG_ENDIAN
```

Comment: You have been downvoted (not by me) because that person probably thinks that this is not an answer. This is correct, and you could have edited your question to add this for later reference. And I think, it is helpful on its own, but still not an answer. Unfortunately, no comment _why_ it is downvoted was posted.

Comment: The order of bytes within a multicharacter constant does not have to be the same as the order of bytes in other objects or the order of bit-fields in a storage unit. the value of a multicharacter constant does not even have to be a concatenation of the values of its characters; its value is implementation-defined. Further, this answer unnecessarily relies on ASCII. (For example, `'\x1\x2'` could have been used to avoid dependence on a character set.)